# Is it possible to escape whitespaces from the filename/path string, using -F cURL for Android

Tags: php, android, curl

I'm trying to run the following cURL/Android command:

```
-i -F uploadedfile=@/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Corre y Se Va/IMG_20170719_223837_2031783171.jpg http://www.runonetworks.com/correyseva/upload_attachment.php?CODE=E49AC1D0
```

However, I'm getting this output:

> curl: (26) couldn't open file "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Corre"

So It looks white spaces are causing trouble with my file path.

I've tried to replace white spaces with "/ " (Without quotes)
Also tried to have the whole string inside quotes ("@/storage...")

I can't seem to find a way to escape the whitespace character.

Does anyone know how?

Comment: what about `"@/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Corre y Se Va/IMG_20170719_223837_2031783171.jpg"` or `@/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Corre\ y\ Se Va/IMG_20170719_223837_2031783171.jpg`?

Comment: Tried both.
The first one seems to give me this:
`curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`
The second one throws the whitespace error.

Comment: Sorry, the first on should be `@"/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Corre y Se Va/IMG_20170719_223837_2031783171.jpg"`

Comment: I actually tried it and it returned `curl: (26) couldn't open file "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Corre y Se Va/IMG_20170719_223837_2031783171.jpg"` so I think you'll be fine

Comment: So I ran this: `-i -F uploadedfile=@"/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Corre y Se Va/IMG_20170719_223837_2031783171.jpg" http://www.runonetworks.com/correyseva/upload_attachment.php?CODE=E49AC1D0`
And got this:
`curl: (26) couldn't open file ""/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Corre"` Noticed the error has two double quotes, strange.

Comment: Indeed, mine only had one double quote at each end so it would probably work if the file existed, but I tested on OSX, not Android. It's clearly taking the double quote as part of the path, hence the space issue remaining

Comment: You can try single quotes as a last resort but I'm pretty sure it will fail too

Comment: Yes, I tried single quotes and failed too.
I don't know what else could I try, or if is it even possible.
It should be implemented, I'm using latest cURL for Android.

Comment: Using curl 7.51.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin16.0) here. As a last resort you can create a symbolic link to that folder and use the symbolic link (with no spaces in it) to access the file, instead of the real target

Answer (score 1):

I just had a look at the cURL man-page, found here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-F

Have you tried `-i -F 'uploadedfile=@/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Corre y Se Va/IMG_20170719_223837_2031783171.jpg' http://www.runonetworks.com/correyseva/upload_attachment.php?CODE=E49AC1D0`?  I've just wrapped the -F value in single quotes.

Answer (score -3):

You,Should migrate path which incluide whitespace with '_' underscore in real path.then use underscored instead of white spaces.

Comment: I can't control the paths, these are paths selected by the App users to upload pictures from, So I should find a way to escape them.